Can I replicate SEM results with only variance-covariance matrix of the summated scores?
I am trying to replicate structural equation modeling results from some research papers using just the variance-covariance matrix.
If the authors estimated the models using observed variables from the measurement model, but provided only the variance-covariance matrix for the latent variables summated scores, will it be possible to replicate the results?
For instance, this paper measures the relationship between three constructs, construct A, B, C, D, and E. Each construct is measured using 5 indicators. However, the author only reported the variance-covariance matrix of the relationships between constructs A, B, C, D, and E. Will it be possible to replicate the result?

You will not be able to fully replicate the results from just the aggregated latent variable scores. You need the covariance matrix of the observed variables (indicators, items) for that purpose.
I would write the authors of the paper to see if they'll be willing share that covariance matrix with you. It would be good scientific practice to do so (in my opinion, the full observed covariance matrix should always be included when reporting CFA/SEM results anyway).
